# Parsing series of formulas from a string using sympy

Tags: sympy

I have a pandas df that contains many string formulas that I would like to be able to parse and eventually solve.  I came across parse_expr and initially seemed like it would work for my problem but now I'm not so sure.
An example string formula might look like this:

```
A = B + C; D = A*.2;
```

`parse_expr` would seem to work well if i had a system of equations and I may not be using this correctly.  As it stands, parse_expr throws an "invalid syntax" error I believe because of the equal sign. Can anyone tell if its possible to solve this problem using parse_expr or if there is another approach I should try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SymPy cannot parse a bunch of semicolon-separated formulas at once, so the string needs to be split first. It will need to be split again at `=`, assuming all formulas have `=` in them. After parsing each side of `=`, you can combine them with `Eq`, which is SymPy's equation object; or use them somehow else.

```
from sympy import S, Eq
str = "A = B + C; D = A*.2;"
result = [Eq(*map(S, f.split("="))) for f in str.split(";")[:-1]]
```

The result is `[Eq(A, B + C), Eq(D, 0.2*A)]`

I use `S`, short for `sympify`; `parse_expr` could be used similarly, and it has a few options that are not needed here.

Comment: A followup questions as I have not been able to resolve regarding use the equation object. If i have a dictionary of variable values i,e, variables = {'A':5,'B':10,'C':15,'D':.3} how does one solve these equations using the Eq object?  I was using a combo of sympify and evalf.  I can pass in a dict into evalf solve for the answer but I have not yet figured if this can be done with the equation object. (Seems like it should be super obvious and I'm sure overlooking something)

Answer (score 0):

`parse_expr` is based on the Python tokenizer, but it has several extensions. These extensions take the form of functions that take a list of tokens, a locals dictionary, and a globals dictionary, and return a modified list of tokens. These are passed as a tuple to `parse_expr`, like `parse_expr(expression, transformations=(transformation1, transformation2, ...))`.

It's probably easiest to just take a look at the [source](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/blob/master/sympy/parsing/sympy_parser.py) of the `sympy.parsing.sympy_parser` submodule to see the existing transformations and how they work. Some of the transformations that are there will probably be useful to you. In this case, you would want a transformation that transforms the `=` token into something else (actually there's already a transformation function `convert_equals_sign` in the `sympy_parser` submodule that does this). You assumedly also want to handle `*.` somehow.

I've also written a guide on Python tokenization which may be helpful here: https://www.asmeurer.com/brown-water-python

If your syntax is too far off from Python's then it will be challenging to use `parse_expr`, since it only works with Python's tokenizer. In that case, you'd need to generate your own grammar and parser (e.g., using antlr) for your DSL and parse it into something that can then be transformed into a SymPy expression.